# How to display text to list if user clicks button in Android app

Tags: c#, android, list, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create an app for Android using C# in Xamarin where the user can select phrases from checkboxes and have them added another page where it will display the results. Below is the code for the results page. My problem is in the add verse button. i am trying to make it so that the user will press the Verse button and it will display the text "Verse" into its own textbox in the list. I am not sure what code I should use. The code I used for it is not properly working. Please help.

```
namespace Songression
{
public class CheckRect{
    public int top{ get; set; }
    public int height{ get; set; }
}


[Activity (Label = "Songression")]          
public class results : Activity, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    //CheckBox[] check;
    List<LinearLayout> linearSet;

    //List<CheckRect> rectList;
    ScrollView scrollView;
    EditText editText = null;
    LinearLayout view;
    bool moveOrEdit = false;
    int screenWidth;

    List<String> checkTextList;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.results);

        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        screenWidth = metrics.WidthPixels;
        //var widthInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.WidthPixels);

        view = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.linearlayout0);
        checkTextList = new List<String>();

        checkTextList.Add ("10 bucks in your pocket and barely making it.");
        checkTextList.Add ("100 steps to the water");
        checkTextList.Add ("18 and going to Hollywood");
        checkTextList.Add ("3 years to propose");

        String checkTextSet = Intent.GetStringExtra ("MyData") ?? "";
        if (checkTextSet == null || checkTextSet == "") {
        } else {
            String[] textSet = checkTextSet.Split (',');
            checkTextList.AddRange (textSet);
        }

        //Back Button
        Button buttonBack = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.buttonBack);
        buttonBack.Click += delegate {
            Finish();
        };

        ///
        //AddLine Button
        Button buttonAdd = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.buttonAdd);
        buttonAdd.Click += delegate {
            addTextPro(false,"");
        };

        ///
        //Add Verse 
        Button buttonVerse = FindViewById <Button> (Resource.Id.buttonVerse);
        buttonVerse.Click += delegate {
            checkTextList.Add(new TextView ("Verse"));
        };
```

Comment: your problem is not clear to me, can you please make it more clear!!

Comment: The problem is in the add verse button. When the user clicks it, they it is supposed to add a textview of the verse to the checkTextList. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help.   ///
        //Add Verse 
        Button buttonVerse = FindViewById <Button> (Resource.Id.buttonVerse);
        buttonVerse.Click += delegate {
            checkTextList.Add(new TextView ("Verse"));
        };

Comment: but your checkTextList is list of string and you are adding TextView in the list!!!!!

Comment: It is nor clear to me either checkTextList is a string list how is this bound to any view? I see nothing related to checkboxes or edittext in the code? Please provide a more complete code sample